# Docker Role for postgres doesn't exist with django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I'm running a docker container that takes a postgres database from another host.

It looks like my docker compose file is connecting to the database
but when i run

`docker exec -it container python manage.py makemigrations` 
or 
`docker exec -it container python manage.py createsuperuser`
i get

```
2019-09-05 23:25:33.553 UTC [29] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres_user"
db_1      | 2019-09-05 23:25:33.553 UTC [29] DETAIL:  Role "postgres_user" does not exist.
db_1      |     Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
db_1      | 2019-09-05 23:26:27.289 UTC [30] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres_user"
db_1      | 2019-09-05 23:26:27.289 UTC [30] DETAIL:  Role "postgres_user" does not exist.
db_1      |     Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

Here is the db portion of my docker compose file

```
db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=host_ip
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=bad_password
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres_database
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgresql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
```

Here is my db settings in my settings.py

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres_database',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD':'bad_password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Running `psql host_db_ip -U postgres_user -W` works fine and I'm able to connect. I tried removed all docker images, containers, and systems and rebuilding everything. My guess is a hashing issue in the docker password?

Comment: Do u find answer?

Comment: @reza_khalafi I don't remember this error but looking at the script it looks like I need the database_name in the settings.py. If you post another question and tag me or post it here I'll take a look at it.